# Changing PSN log-in on one user

Tags: ps3, psn

I accidentally used my old PSN log-in on my primary gaming user, is there a way to log into my new PSN account on that one user? I tried logging out and logging into the new one, but it said I cannot sign in using another users sign in ID. Please tell me, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I assume you mean profiles on your machine? You can create a new profile and log in from it, you can even make sure that new profile is the default one when you turn on the machine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to fix this PSN flaw.

On first online sign-in with a local user, that PSN name is permanantly associated with that local user. That PSN name is saved as read only; any attempt to log-in with another user name fails (as you have seen).

The only solution you have is to make a new local user and associate the correct PSN name with it.

Theortically, to backup all your save games and stuff you would attach some form of USB hard drive, copy over all user information, delete that account, create a new account with EXACT same name, and then copy over the data into the new user account.

**WARNING:** I have tried this twice for my girlfriend and once for another friend, none of those times was the save data or trophies able to be used by the new account.

**DO AT YOUR OWN RISK**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You have to do "*restore default settings*" from the hidden menu (press the power button wait for the first beep and leave it)

When you do, **you are going to lose, messages, PS3 settings, passwords and emails.** After the restore you can match your user name with your correct PSN id.